# Clockify API, unexpected data returned?

Tags: python, clockify

I'm requesting some time entries for users with the [Clockify API](https://clockify.me/developers-api#operation--v1-workspaces--workspaceId--user--userId--time-entries-get)(). For some reason, I am receiving some responses which include entries without an end-time.  I noticed that, the unexpectedly returned entries belong to currently running time entires...  However, I did not specify/use the 'in-progress' parameter...  What is happening here?

**Here is my code:**

```py
def fetch_users_time_entries(users):
    API_URL = "https://api.clockify.me/api/v1"
    for user in users:
        url = "{}/workspaces/{}/user/{}/time-entries?hydrated=true&page-size=1000&start=2019-08-05T00:00:01Z".format(API_URL, WORKSPACE_ID, user['clockify_id'])
        time_entries = requests.get(url, headers=HEADER)
        for time_entry in time_entries.json():
```

**Here is a sample of an unexpected "end" value:**

```
{  
   'id':'SECRET',
   'description':'',
   'tags':[  
      {  
         'id':'SECRET',
         'name':'CERTI',
         'workspaceId':'SECRET'
      }
   ],
   'user':None,
   'billable':True,
   'task':{  
      'id':'SECRET',
      'name':'Etapa: Execução e Controle',
      'projectId':'SECRET',
      'assigneeId':'',
      'estimate':'PT0S',
      'status':'ACTIVE'
   },
   'project':{  
      'id':'SECRET',
      'name':'C105',
      'hourlyRate':{  
         'amount':0,
         'currency':'USD'
      },
      'clientId':'SECRET',
      'workspaceId':'SECRET',
      'billable':True,
      'memberships':[  
         {  
            'userId':'SECRET',
            'hourlyRate':None,
            'targetId':'SECRET',
            'membershipType':'PROJECT',
            'membershipStatus':'ACTIVE'
         }
      ],
      'color':'#8bc34a',
      'estimate':{  
         'estimate':'PT0S',
         'type':'AUTO'
      },
      'archived':False,
      'duration':'PT25H20M12S',
      'clientName':'NEO',
      'public':True
   },
   'timeInterval':{  
      'start':'2019-08-22T18:55:55Z',
      'end':None,
      'duration':None
   },
   'workspaceId':'SECRET',
   'totalBillable':None,
   'hourlyRate':None,
   'isLocked':False,
   'userId':'SECRET',
   'projectId':'SECRET'
}
```

I was only expecting time entries that were completed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE (10/16/19):**

> Another follow-up. They just send me an e-mail saying they fixed the problem. Putting the parameter "in-progress" to false will return only completed time entries. @matthew-e-miller it would be nice to add this to the answer. – Lukas Belck 5 hours ago

---

Okay, so I finally had a chance to reproduce the problem and it seems... There is not an end-time filter.  They have misleadingly provided a start and end parameter, **but these both filter on start-time**.

**The start and end parameters work like this:**

[image: Clockify Start and End Overview]

The in-progress works as described in the [doc](https://clockify.me/developers-api#/definitions/ClientDto), but it doesn't work for your application.

**Answer:**

I think your best bet is to request all the time entries, place them into a dict/list, and then use your python script to remove elements with "'end: 'None'".

```
import requests
import json

headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "X-Api-Key": "your api key""}

workspaceId = "your workspace id"
userId = "your user id"
params = {'start': '2019-08-28T11:10:32.998Z', 'end': '2019-08-29T02:05:02Z', 'in-progress': 'true'}
API_URL = "https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/user/{userId}/time-entries"

print(API_URL)
result_one = requests.get(API_URL, headers=headers, params=params)
print(result_one)
List = json.loads(result_one.text)
for entry in List:
    if entry.get("timeInterval")['end'] == None:
      List.remove(entry)
print(List)
```

**Output:**

List containing only entries which do not have timeInterval.end == 'None'.

**Here is time spent on this answer-edit:**

[image: Clockify Time Spent On Question]

Comment: Even using the end-time parameter I'm still receiving time entries without end-time

Comment: Okay, I'll recreate the problem and let you know.

Comment: @matthwe-e-miller Did you manage to recreate the problem? I also tried setting the in-progress parameter to false, but it didn't work. If you want I can share some pictures with the requests showing the time-entry with no end-time, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @LukasBelck I finally had a chance to recreate the problem.  I edited my answer to reflect what I found about the API.  I explained everything in this newly-edited answer.  I hope this helps.  It definitely solves your problem, so give it a check mark if you're satisfied.

Comment: @matthwe-e-miller thanks for the answer. I didn't know the end parameter was actually for the start-date. I was already removing the entries without end-time but wanted a clever/cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Just a follow-up. I got in contact with Clockify support and it seems that the "in-progress" parameter is not working and they are working on it. Setting the "in-progress" to false should return only time entries with end-time.

Comment: Another follow-up. They just send me an e-mail saying they fixed the problem. Putting the parameter "in-progress" to false will return only completed time entries. @matthwe-e-miller it would be nice to add this to the answer.

Comment: @LukasBelck added.